# How are overlong UTF-8 encodings generated?

Tags: utf-8

Many of the questions on Stack Overflow about overlong UTF-8 sequences have to do with detecting and preventing them. My question is, where do these sequences come from? How are they generated? I've looked over the Wikipedia article on UTF-8 encoding and several other questions here on Stack Overflow, but I can't figure out how to generate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629), Unicode characters U+0080 to U+07FF use the 2-byte UTF-8 encoding that encodes up to 11 bits, for example:

> U+0080 = 00010000000<sub>bin</sub> (leading zeros for 11 bits)
> UTF-8 2-byte encoding pattern = **110**xxxxx **10**xxxxxx<sub>bin</sub>

Distributing the first 5 bits in the first byte and last 6 bits in the second byte:

> **110**00010 **10**000000<sub>bin</sub> = C2 80<sub>hex</sub>

You make an overlong UTF-8 encoding by, for example, using a longer encoding on a Unicode code point below the acceptable range, for example, U+007F is in the 1-byte encoding range and should be encoded as 7F<sub>hex</sub>, but it can be overlong-encoded as:

> U+007F = 01111111<sub>bin</sub>
>
> 2-byte: **110**00001 **10**111111<sub>bin</sub> = C1 BF<sub>hex</sub>
> 3-byte: **1110**0000 **10**000001 **10**111111<sub>bin</sub> = E0 81 BF<sub>hex</sub>
> 4-byte: **11110**000 **10**000000 **10**000001 **10**111111<sub>bin</sub> = F0 80 81 BF<sub>hex</sub>

These overlong encodings are illegal.  The shortest encoding should always be used.

Here's an example of the Python language detecting them:

```
>>> b'\xc1\xbf'.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: invalid start byte
>>> b'\xe0\x81\xbf'.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
>>> b'\xf0\x80\x81\xbf'.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
>>> b'\x7f'.decode('utf8')
'\x7f'
```

Comment: That's extremely helpful, thank you! So if I wanted to encode a comma (U+0002C), for example, the two byte encoding would be C0 AC?